# How to add a file to serializeArray

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a wizard with different forms on every step. In one of the steps I have cropper for images and on next step I want to send crop data to controller method but I can't add that to `serializeArray`. This is my js part:

```
wizard.on('beforeNext', function (wizardObj) {
                    wizardObj.stop();
                    let wizardForm = $('#kt_form_' + wizardObj.currentStep)
                    let dataForm = wizardForm.serializeArray()
                    if (wizardObj.currentStep == 2) {
                        canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                            width: 160,
                            height: 160,
                        });
                        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                            url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                            reader.onloadend = function () {
                                var base64data = reader.result;
                                dataForm.push({ name: "cropImage", value: base64data });
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    let url = wizardForm.attr('action')
                    let method = wizardForm.attr('method')
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: method,
                        data: dataForm,
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        wizardObj.goNext();
                    })
```

When I console log a dataForm I see that I have cropImage attribute but on controller method it's not part of request when I `dd($request->all())`